# Where is the "event horizon" on a basketball hoop?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life

I'm watching a lot of basketball [this month](http://www.ncaa.com/march-madness). A common event is the ball going part way into the hoop and then coming out again. Announcers sometimes claim that the ball was "halfway through" when it rims out. Thinking about it, with enough rotation and friction I wouldn't be surprised if the ball *could* fall that far and not go through. How far can a basketball fall without being certain to fall all the way through?

---

Assuming we are talking about [NCAA men's basketball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball_%28ball%29#Modern-day_specifications) the **relevant data:**

```
Circumference of the ball: 29.5-30 inches (749–762 mm)
Weight of the ball:        20-22 ounces   (567–624 g)
Bounce of the ball:        49-54 inches   (1245–1372 mm) when dropped 6 feet (1829 mm)
Diameter of the rim:       18 inches      (457 mm)
Coefficient of friction*:  1.2
```

The coefficient of friction between the rim and the ball was estimated in [The Engineering of Sport 7: Vol. 1
 By Margaret Estivalet, Pierre Brisson](http://books.google.com/books?id=optom1F4uLEC&pg=PA707&lpg=PA707&dq=basketball+coefficient+of+friction&source=bl&ots=6wKffLkVnr&sig=s17DXd37E2oGTiP2-L7St3rMIK0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ho0sU7TwBtLEoASRtoCIAw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=basketball%20coefficient%20of%20friction&f=false). I assume the synthetic cover is used. For leather, the coefficient of friction was estimated at 0.5.

For the purpose of this question, let's assume any rotational speed is possible. (It should be possible to estimate what humans can achieve, but obviously there is a limit.) Also, assume that gravity (and air pressure, if it matters) is at sea level.

Comment: are we just considering the rim and not the net?

Comment: @DavePhD: Hmmm... Hadn't thought about the net. I suppose if it came into play that would be good to factor in too. But I can't think of any way it would help unless it were tied off or something.

Comment: Last weekend I had a basketball match and the baskets had fairly short and narrow nets. During the warming up one shot passed more than halfway below the trim but somehow got thrown out again by the net. Fortunately it this did not occur during the match itself.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, if you don't limit the rotational speed, The ball going halfway through and coming back out is (probably) possible.

All you gotta do is spin it fast enough in the right direction and launch it at the right angle so that it hits the rim perpendicularly. The normal impulse due to the collision will generate a frictional impulse upward, which will "kick" the ball upward.

So by changing the velocity with which the ball collides, we can probably achieve the appropriate final velocity to get the ball out after going halfway in.

One more thing, you have to spin the ball in the "forward" direction (direction in which you are throwing it) which is odd and looks difficult when you have to spin it really fast.

Comment: I haven't checked the math, and there is a chance this is not possible. I leave that for you to determine.

Comment: I recently saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdgpLKcEgaw) which illustrates this.

Comment: @fibonatic, nice one there! You could do the same with a basketball in a single bounce off the rim, but as I said, it will require a high enough rotational speed